# Android detect missed call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, android-toast

I am attempting to have my application recognize when there is a missed call. I have created a BroadcastReceiver that detects when the phone's state has changed. Here is my `onReceive()` method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean ringing = false, callReceived = false;
    String callerPhoneNumber = "";
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
        ringing = true;
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        callerPhoneNumber= bundle.getString("incoming_number");

        if (ringing) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone call from: " + callerPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
        callReceived = true;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
//          Toast.makeText(context, "Phone is idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (ringing) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ringing is true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

//          if (ringing && !callReceived) {
//              Toast.makeText(context, "It was A MISSED CALL from : " + callerPhoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }
    }
```

The issue I am having is the application detects when the phone is ringing, sets `ringing` to `true`, and shows the appropriate toast message. However, when the phone's state is `idle`, it does not enter the `if (ringing)` statement to show the `ringing is true` toast message. However, if I comment in the toast message just above it, it will correctly print that the `Phone is idle`.

Is it possible that `ringing` is being reset to `false` somewhere between the phone ringing and the phone becoming idle again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not store any "state" information in a broadcast receiver. If you want to do a comparison old state / new state, I think you can use a service.

Comment: exact, when onReceive is called it's a new instance, so no previous values are keep. You can keep this on preferences between BroadcastReceiver calls

Comment: Thanks, I made it a static variable and it is working well now.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to NOT use static variable. The OS can unload your class from memory and you can loose the information anyway. Use a service to keep your data around.

Comment: @greywolf82 is right. I am also experiencing the same problem with BroadcastReceiver.